# Avoid elements from an array that does not meet criteria

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, excel-2007

Ok... The below line puts content of the array myArr in cell A1

`sh.Range("A1").Resize(cnt, 7).Value = myArr`

Here are some sample records the above line outputs

```
18  5   1   23  15  7   6
23  5   3   10  18  20  15
19  10  25  12  21  15  23
10  14  11  9   7   25  20
24  15  23  20  11  17  2
7   15  3   16  24  22  13
14  4   15  13  6   23  2
20  11  22  24  14  3   6
17  5   13  15  19  6   22
9   13  15  7   24  3   6
```

Before this line, I need a condition and not sure how to write the syntax.
I want to add up all 7 values of the first element (`lbound`) and check the sum and do it for all the elements till (`ubound`). And run the above line **only** if the total is equal to 100

Once the first query is resolved, I also have a **second query** to list only the count as to how many elements added up to a total of 100, how many elements had a sum of 80 and so on.... by adding another array that takes info from the first array. The count will be between 75 to 125. The expected output should be

```
75 1
76 0
77 2
.
.
.
125 1
```

This is what I am trying

```
Sub foo()
Dim myArr(1 To 10)
Dim cnt As Integer, i As Integer
myArr(1) = "18,5,1,23,15,7,6"
myArr(2) = "23,5,3,10,18,20,15"
myArr(3) = "19,10,25,12,21,15,23"
myArr(4) = "10,14,11,9,7,25,20"
myArr(5) = "24,15,23,20,11,17,2"
myArr(6) = "7,15,3,16,24,22,13"
myArr(7) = "14,4,15,13,6,23,2"
myArr(8) = "20,11,22,24,14,3,6"
myArr(9) = "17,5,13,15,19,6,22"
myArr(10) = "9,13,15,7,24,3,6"
For i = 1 To UBound(myArr)
With Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum = .Sum(.Index(myArr, i, 0))
    'if ....
        '....
    'endif
End With
Range("A1").Resize(cnt, 7).Value = myArr
End Sub
```

Comment: Show us the code you have written so far and tell us the problems you are having with it.

Comment: By element do you mean row? And if looping the rows is it each row = 100 or total of each row total = 100? Latter seems to make more sense.  Some sample data would help.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The code is nothing to do with the problem i am facing. I am getting the result in my sheet in the range A1:G250 which is an output of the line mentioned in the question. My only question is that instead of just filling 250 rows, just fill only few rows where total of the rows is 100.

Comment: Yes... by element, I mean row. Total of A1:G1 should be 100. if not, then dont list it. I want to do it when the array is ready even before it is listed in the worksheet. Second query is that, instead of listing the values, list the sum of every row corresponding to its value. I hope I have explained it well.

Comment: I have added sample data for your reference

Comment: Starter for the row totals For i =1 to cnt With Application.WorksheetFunction
   Sum = .Sum(.Index(myArr, i, 0))
End With

Comment: I have updated my question with a sample code with the help you provided but I am getting error near `.sum` I am also not sure of the index on how to keep the two rows which totals 100 and how to remove the remaining rows fromt the array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156749/discussion-between-qharr-and-sabha).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see for Part 1 & part 2 following on from chat here:[Comments moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156749/discussion-between-qharr-and-sabha)
This splits your string into its elements, converts to ints and sums. It then performs a check so see if = 100 and if so adds to an array that can then be written out to sheet. I can't help but think there might be a more efficient way then using so many arrays but haven't thought of it yet.

```
Sub foo()

Dim myArr(1 To 10)
Dim TotalsArr(1 to 10) 
Dim cnt As Integer, i As Integer

myArr(1) = "18,5,1,23,15,7,6"
myArr(2) = "23,5,3,10,18,20,15"
myArr(3) = "19,10,25,12,21,15,23"
myArr(4) = "10,14,11,9,7,25,20"
myArr(5) = "24,15,23,20,11,17,2"
myArr(6) = "7,15,3,16,24,22,13"
myArr(7) = "14,4,15,13,6,23,2"
myArr(8) = "20,11,22,24,14,3,6"
myArr(9) = "17,5,13,15,19,6,22"
myArr(10) = "9,13,15,7,24,3,6"

Dim tempArr as Variant
Dim Val as Variant
Dim Total as Long
Dim Counter As Long
Dim FinalArr()
```

Part 1: Calculating the item totals and checking if =100, then add to result Array.

```
Counter = 0
For i = LBound(myArr) to UBound(myArr)
    Total = 0
    tempArr = Split(myArr(i),",")

    For Each Val in tempArr
        Total = Total + Val
    Next Val
    If Total = 100 Then
        ReDim Preserve FinalArr(Counter)
        FinalArr(Counter) = myArr(i)
        Counter = Counter + 1
    End If

    TotalsArr(i) = Total 'store totals for later use in dictionary
Next i    

For i = LBound(FinalArr) to UBound(FinalArr)
    Debug.Print FinalArr(i)
Next i
```

Part 2: Getting a count of each distinct total.
   We will use a dictionary to store the count of each key (total) and overwrite when the same key is found again adding one to the value (i.e. count)

```
Dim totalsDict As Scripting.Dictionary 'Tools > references > add in microsoft scripting runtime
Dim key as Variant

Set totalsDict = New Scripting.Dictionary

'If prepopulating with totals to check for in range 75 to 125 ( otherwise comment out next 3 code lines

For i = 75 to 125
    totalsdict.Add i , 0
Next i

For i = LBound(TotalsArr) to UBound(TotalsArr)
        totalsDict(TotalsArr(i)) = totalsDict(TotalsArr(i)) + 1 'will overwrite adding one to value
Next i

For Each key in totalsdict.Keys
    Debug.print key, "," , totalsDict(key)
Next key

End Sub
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you so very much for the time and effort you took for me. God bless!

Comment: I am struggling to rewrite the code if the array was a multidimensional one to avoid/eliminate the use of tempArr. Can you please explain if the array was of 10 rows and 7 columns then how would you edit the code? Also what would go inside of `For Each key in totalsdict.Keys` to save the result in a 2D array and finally output the entire array result in A1? Thanks